# bootstrap nav-bar collapse icon not triggering in codepen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've constructed a bootstrap navbar on codepen which collapses for mobile and displays an icon-bar, which when clicked should expand the menu, however the menu wont expand when clicked. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've enabled bootstrap on the CSS page and jquery and bootstrap on the Javascript page.

Here's the link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/bonfirehead/pen/xVxRxq

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">


      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-   target="#myNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column-xs-6 background1">
    </div>



    <h2 class="background2 nopadding text-center"></h2>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-xs-6">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error on codepen or codeply - the mobile style dropdown on the navbar displays correctly upon clicking it.

That being said, on line 24, you have a closing `</nav>` tag, but the opening tag is missing. On line 32, you have an unopened `</p>` tag, and again on line 37 with an unopened `</div>`. I've seen in the past that HTML can be a bit finnicky when it comes to things like this, so try correcting those and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I fixed up the HTML as per your suggestion and it's working fine now. Thanks so much for your help. Much appreciated!!